# Can a client have two connections at the same time to the same socket listener?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, sockets, xamarin.android

We have a server that's listening on port 17700 and a client that wants to synchronize its data but the client is multi-threaded and sets a connection up on two threads to the same port at the same time. When we look at the data that is received we noticed that the packages that were sent were "mixed" with each other.

*My Theory*

*The server sends packages to the client which address is exactly the same, so the client doesn't know which packages are for which thread.*

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to use a concurrent queue so the packets shouldn't be massed up. Cleaner solution would be each connection has it's own socket on both sides. ( + 1 Listener to accept connections )

Comment: Thanks DarkIrata, we now use multiple sockets and it works